# Stopping a iframe from loading a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, comet

Is there a way in javascript of stopping an iframe in the middle of loading a page? The reason I need to do this is I have a background iframe streaming data from a web server (via a Comet style mechanism) and I need to be able to sever the connection at will.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Not confident enough to put it as an answer, but couldn't you just direct the iframe to another url? Something like `document.getElementById("myiframe").src = "http://www.example.com/not-long-polling.html";`

Comment: That was my first idea (+1), but I need the contents of the frame to be preserved.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For FireFox/Safari/Chrome you can use window.stop():

```
window.frames[0].stop()
```

For IE, you can do the same thing with document.execCommand('Stop'):

```
window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop')
```

For a cross-browser solution you could use:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
  window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');
} else {
  window.frames[0].stop();
}
```

Comment: It is probably better to check for `typeof(window.frames[0].stop)` instead of `navigator.appName`. Future IE version may support that.

Comment: @unclenorton i don't really get what you trying to say. you may write the condition ?

Comment: @MorSela, I am trying to say that it is better to check for a feature rather than for a browser. The condition will look like `(typeof (window.frames[0].stop === 'undefined')`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I agree with unclenorton : it's better to test the presence of a feature itself instead of testing the browser.

Comment: Alex's example using typeof() works pefectly. upvoting that answer for others to find faster

Comment: For those who are using jQuery, i had problems while testing the `stop` function, because of the [jQuery method with the same name](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). To solve this, I used javascript dom selectors like this:  `document.getElementById("myId").getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]`. I don't know if there's an easy alternative for this, but it does the job.

Comment: As addition to @v42, after getting the frame, you have to target the contentWindow:
`var iframe = document.getElementById("myId").getElementsByTagName('iframe‌​')[0].contentWindow;`

Answer (score 13):

The whole code should be like this, (unclenorton's line was missing a bracket)

```
if (typeof (window.frames[0].stop) === 'undefined'){
    //Internet Explorer code
    setTimeout(function() {window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');},1000);
}else{
    //Other browsers
    setTimeout(function() {window.frames[0].stop();},1000);
}
```

Comment: Why is `setTimeout` used?

Answer (score 1):

Merely,

```
document.getElementById("myiframe").src = '';
```

Comment: That doesn't stop large and heavy javascript execution, like Unity WebGL Build.

Answer (score 1):

## Very easy:

1) Get the iframe or img you don't want to load:

```
let myIframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe')
```

2) Then you can just replace src attribute to about.blank:

```
myIframe.src = 'about:blank'
```

That's all.

---

If you wanted to load the iframe or image at a time in feature when some event happens then just store the src variable in [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
myIframe.dataset.srcBackup = myIframe.src
// then replace by about blank
myIframe.src = 'about:blank'
```

Now you can use it when needed easily:

```
myIframe.src = myIframe.dataset.srcBackup
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a reference to the element, you need to use `.contentX` to get the `document`/`window` to run the accepted answer.
Checking that the iframe actually has a document is also necessary for dynamically added iframe elements.

```js
function stopIframe(element) {
    var doc = element.contentDocument;
    //iframes wont have a document if they aren't loading/loaded
    //check so JS wont throw
    if (!doc)
        return;

    //try for modern browsers
    if (doc.defaultView.stop)
        doc.defaultView.stop();
    //fallback for IE
    else
        doc.execCommand('Stop');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> not support in IE

```
<script>
function stopit() {
window.stop();

};
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="stopit()" class="Stop" title="Stop"></a>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the accepted answer, I think it is quite equal to what you posted