# Stop iframe from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have iframe and i'm uploading files through it, so my question is how can i stop it in the middle of the loading? I've tried to change src with jquery function `attr()` but i didn't do any good, i'm thinking of removing the whole iframe with `js` but it would create me other problems and i'm not even sure if it would work. So is there some other ways to do it?

My next question would be, is it possible to hide loading indicators so it wouldn't confuse users that page is loading or something.

Answers like you should use flash or other stuff won't be accepted i already did everything with iframe i just need to do those 2 things.

Here is my iframe code:

```
<iframe onload="file_uploaded()" class="iframe" src="user/upload_image/" name="iframeTarget" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the src using `document.location`?

Comment: @michielvoo can you be more specific, i've tried to do it like this
`document.getElementById('myId').location="#"` ofc i gave my iframe id `myId` but it didn't work

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById('myId').document.location`.  And I don't think `"#"` will work. You'd have to navigate to another location to cancel the operation inside the iframe, but `#` is just an unnamed anchor inside the current page. But overall, you'd be better off using the answer given below by Rick Kuipers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping a iframe from loading a page using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207501/stopping-a-iframe-from-loading-a-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe the following answers your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207589/1157493

> For FireFox/Safari/Chrome you can use window.stop():
>
> ```
> window.frames[0].stop()
> ```
>
> For IE, you can do the same thing with document.execCommand('Stop'):
>
> ```
> window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop')
> ```
>
> For a cross-browser solution you could use:
>
> ```
> if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
>   window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');
> } else {
>   window.frames[0].stop();
> }
> ```

If you'd like the iframe to go to a different page you could try to redirect it to "about:blank"

Comment: Thanks it worked, now how can i remove that annoying loading indicator so user wouldn't see that page is loading?

Comment: Can you explain which loading indicator you are talking about? If we're talking about cursors then using CSS `cursor:default;` would solve this.

Comment: no i'm talking about all the stuff which is showing that page is being loaded for example in firefox in right bottom corner there is box which is showing all elements being loaded well you know what i mean... i wanna make it so it would look that i'm using ajax but i'm actualy not

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to avoid that. The browser simply won't let you have control over that. As far as I know.

Comment: to avoid issue using jquery, use: `document.getElementById("myId").getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].stop();`

Comment: this method only works if the frames (iframes) have a `src` in same domain of the parent page, otherwise you get permission errors to access any property/function inside the frame, even the `stop()`

Answer (score 9):

This works for me (IE, Chrome, FF, Opera):

```
$iframe.attr('src','about:blank');
```

Comment: this is actually a good solution when you have nothing to do with the page and its URL, and the frame (iframe) is on another domain.
**the pure js version:** `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = "about:blank";` remember you can't use the `frames[0]` because it gives you the `window` inside the iframe, not the iframe element in your page with the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

can use this for disabling all iframe content

```
<script>
    var frames = window.frames;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        frames[i].location = "";
    }
</script>
```