# Aborting the parser from JavaScript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In Gecko and WebKit, you can abort the active HTML parser by calling `window.stop()` on the `Window` object of the browsing context that's hosting the document.

Is there way to abort the HTML parser from JavaScript in IE without causing navigation elsewhere (`window.location`) and without deleting the contents of the document and immediately creating a new parser (`document.open()`)?

That is, is there a way to use JavaScript to trigger the effect of the user pressing the Stop button?

(The use case is studying the effects of aborting the parser in IE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Stop iframe from loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961455/stop-iframe-from-loading)

Quote:

*For IE, you can do the same thing with document.execCommand('Stop'):*

```
window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop')
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, when called on a document with a script-created parser (`document.open()`ed document), `execCommand` doesn't abort the parser.