# Stop page load after 10 sec javascript

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem, on my website i am using

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown'),
        downloadButton = document.getElementById('new_download'),
        seconds = 10 ,
        second = 0,
        interval;

        downloadButton.style.display = 'none';

        interval = setInterval(function() {

            if (second >= seconds) {
                downloadButton.style.display = 'block';
                countdownElement.style.display = 'none';
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            second++;
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

But some google ads keep on loading and this function don't work. so i thought to stop page load after 10 sec  with this script in footer of page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     setTimeout( function(){ 
    window.stop() 
  }  , 10000 );
    </script>
```

But this is not working, is there any way i can stop page load after some time or skip google ads load time from page load time or other method except `window.onload` function

Comment: ... You have Google ads on your website... that you want to block?

Comment: You could ruin users with slow data connection with that script..

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No i want them to stop load after 10 sec ... some ads load for ever.

Comment: Related: [Stopping a iframe from loading a page using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207501/stopping-a-iframe-from-loading-a-page-using-javascript).  Second answer demonstrates using window.stop() with setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick jquery code i wrote which worked for me...although i had no google ads. and i got rid of the `setInterval()`
  hope it helps..

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$("#new_download").css({
"display":"none"
});
setTimeout(displaydbutton,10000);
} 
function displaydbutton(){
$("#dload").css({
"display":"block"
});
clearTimeout();
});
```